# How to remove all newlines in an array without using for loop with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I would like to remove all newlines without using `for` loop and then the array might changed the order. The code must go at the commented line of code below.

```
string[] filterInput1 = tbInput1.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
//(remove all Environment.NewLine or "" code goes here).
string after_resultInput1 = "";
for (int i = 0; i < filterInput1.Length; i++)
{
    string[] getDict = filterInput1[i].Split(new char[] { Convert.ToChar(tbDelim.Text) });
    after_resultInput1 += getDict[Convert.ToInt32(tbColumn.Text)] + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

**The array of filterInput1 after `Split()`**

```
filterInput1
{string[6]}
[0]: "asdasdasd|abc"
[1]: ""
[2]: ""
[3]: "1111"
[4]: ""
[5]: ""
```

**The result must be:**

```
filterInput1
{string[2]}
[0]: "asdasdasd|abc"
[1]: "1111"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`:

```
string[] filterInput1 = tbInput1.Text.Split(
    new string[] { Environment.NewLine },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try RemoveEmptyEntries like AlexD suggested:

```
string[] filterInput1 = tbInput1.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Good luck with your quest.

If you allow linq you could do something like this:

```
after_resultInput1 = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    tbInput1.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
    SelectMany(s => s.Split(new char[] { Convert.ToChar(tbDelim.Text) })));
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your additional comment about LINQ. Which one will run faster?

Comment: This one runs faster than yours since yours uses += and my example uses string.Join which in turn uses StringBuilder.  That is the theory, but in your case no one would ever notice.

Comment: Because of a large amount of the array, I am looking for the best solution to solve my problem above and the fastest code also. Thank you again, your code is very awesome with the additional code.

Comment: @PMay1903: The answer to "which one will run faster?" is always the same: get out a stopwatch, run the code both ways, and then you will know.